# How to deal with time consuming backend tasks in ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, frontend, backend

In my project, I make ajax call from frontend(React) to backend(Laravel) using axios.
There are many things to do in backend function and it takes a lot of time. I'm getting a connection timed out error whenever I make a call.
I need to receive the result of the backend job (success, error, etc.).
What is the best solution to accomplish this requirement?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use ServerSentEvent(look at EventSource), Long polling(google it) or change server timeout.

Comment: Server Sent Event was a useful tool.It did help me to improve user experience by the real-time updates. But it didn't solve the timeout problem. If the callback function of the StreamedResponse class (Laravel) takes more than 60 seconds to execute, the server throws PHP Fatal error. `PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in ... .php on line 52`. Maybe modifying the `max_execution_time` value is the only way?

Comment: You must use something like a task-manager. Immediately return a task id to client before send a response with task-id as a SSE when the operation is done. If you run the operation as an asynchronous job so that never be timeout because server immediately responses. Another and simpler way is long-polling, it's similar to SSE but instead of listening an event, client continuously asks server that if the operation is done or not in a specified time period until the operation is done.

Comment: Those are appropriate ways to handle expensive tasks.